# when collection is submitted back to controller get Object reference not set to an instance of an object. error

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am updating multiple records and after I click submit button I get the error, which indicates that controller receives NULL and reports the following error at line 36
Below is the code for my controller, view and the model.

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>           Description:
>
> An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace
>   for more information about the error and where it originated in the
>   code. 
>            Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
    Source Error: 

    Line 34:         public ActionResult UpdateAll(ICollection<Test0> test0s)
    Line 35:         {
    Line 36:             foreach (var tst in test0s)
    Line 37:             {
    Line 38:                 if (ModelState.IsValid)

    Source File: c:\users\rsc_vok\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\MvcTest0\MvcTest0\Controllers\Test0Controller.cs    Line: 36
```

Here is the model:

```
namespace MvcTest0.Models
{
    public class Test0
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public int SectnID { get; set; }
        public string Section { get; set; }
        public string Comment { get; set; }
    }

    public class Test0DBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Test0> Test0s { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And here is my controller code:

```
    public ActionResult UpdateAll(int id=0)
    {
        int sectnid = id;
        List<Test0> records = db.Test0s.ToList();
        var Sectnrecord = from r in records
                        where r.SectnID == sectnid
                        select r;

        return View(Sectnrecord.ToList());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UpdateAll(ICollection<Test0> test0s)
    {
        foreach (var tst in test0s)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(tst).State = EntityState.Modified;
            }
        }
        db.SaveChanges();

        return View(test0s);
    }
```

And here is my view

```
      @model IEnumerable<MvcTest0.Models.Test0>

      @{
      ViewBag.Title = "UpdateAll";
     }

    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

   @using (Html.BeginForm())
   {
       @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

       var sectnHeader = new String[10];
       sectnHeader[0] = "A. QUALITY";
       sectnHeader[1] = "B. VR REFERRAL";
       var items = Model.ToArray();
       var sections = 1;
       for (var sectnLoop = 0; sectnLoop < sections; sectnLoop++)
       {
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b>@(sectnHeader[sectnLoop])</b>
                    </td>
                </tr>  
            </table>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>SectnID</th>
                    <th>Section</th>
                    <th>Comment</th>
                </tr>

            </table>
           for (var i = sectnLoop * 2; i < sectnLoop * 2 + 2; i++)
           {
               var sctnid = "sectnname" + i;
               @Html.HiddenFor(m => items[i].id)
               @Html.HiddenFor(m => items[i].SectnID)

               <table>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(m => items[i].SectnID)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.EditorFor(m => items[i].Section)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => items[i].Section)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.EditorFor(m => items[i].Comment)
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => items[i].Comment)
                    </td>
                 </tr>
                </table> 
           } 
       } 
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
   }
```

Comment: The code of the View immediately follows the code of the controller above, which is followed by the MODEL - sorry I couldn't separate them well when I was posting the question.

Comment: did you try `FormCollection coll` instead of your typed list `ICollection<Test0> test0s` ?bcoz i suspect its not able to populate your given model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution:

1. You have to change the view model to a collection type which support `.Add()` method:

   `@model List<MvcTest0.Models.Test0>`
2. Change all the `@Html.___For()` helpers like:

   ```
   @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].id)
   @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].SectnID)
   @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].SectnID)
   @Html.EditorFor(m => m[i].Section)
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m[i].Section)
   @Html.EditorFor(m => m[i].Comment)
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m[i].Comment)
   ```

Notice that model has to be recreated in post back and IEnumerable has no method to add items to itself, unlike generic List.

Comment: What Tohid said. You can't use interfaces for action method parameters. Think of action method parameters as dumb DTOs, not as domain objects with behavior.

Comment: Ack! For example, in the case with `ICollection`, what would MVC create? There are an infinite number of possible classes that implement ICollection. MVC needs a concrete class as an argument.

Comment: Wow! This is my lucky day. The big Phil Haack (@Haacked) approved my answer. Yooohooo :) I'm so happy. Thank you Phil. I'm a big fan of your blog by the way.

Comment: @user1456934 - Please mark my answer as accepted so I get rank and other people find out that it works.